# 2d array for gradebook

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, parsing, csv

This is my first attempt at programming anything with mac. The learning curve is steep. I have a .csv file with several columns of ascii data organized blank field, username, name (in format "last name, firstname middle name"), assignment 1 grade (integer), assignment 2 grade (integer).... assignment n grade (integer), grade avg (with one grade dropped), section number (integer).
In lieu of a grade their may be a text entry in the assignment column: I for ill, X for exempt etc.
I need to calculate a grade average for each assignment by section. I'e. the average grade for students in section 9999 is **__**. I have looked at various parsing schemes but the are much too complex at this point in my understanding of objective c to know how to use them, let alone how they work. So am linking for something more specific and less universal.

I have written some code to read the file into a long string.
I have written code to break the string into an array of lines of code (grades by student n)
I am stymied on how to break up the array of lines into a 2d array of lines of items.
Once I've done that I want to calculate the section average for each assignment by looking at each column of grades for an individual assignemnt. If the student for that row is inthe section I am calculating I want to sum the numeric grades, skipping any S or X entries and divide by the number of numeric entries to get the average for that assignment.

Eventually I will output a csv file that has section number, average grade for each assignment, cumulative grade for each assignment.

So for my first question, how to break up the array into items and how to access the individual items using numeric indexes? Any constructive guidance will be most graciously accepted.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
    // main.m


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

     @autoreleasepool
    {

        // insert code here...

        // beginning of sample code ************************************

        // content is a pointer to a string containing all the data from the file
        // contentarray is a pointer to an array where each index is a line from the file (separated by \n
        // itemarray is a pointer to an array where the primary index - row is the nth line of the file and column is the nth item in the line.

        NSInteger   itemcount, rowcount;
        NSString *pathwithgradefile = @"/some_path/sampledata.csv";
        // NSError *error = nil;

        NSString *content =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathwithgradefile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",content);

        Make array of lines from the file - This part works. 
       NSArray *contentArray = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; // csv file line ends with newline

        // output check of contentarray.
        NSLog(@" \nlist contentArray line by line\n");   


        rowcount=0;
        for (NSString *item in contentArray) {
            // display item
                        NSLog(@"\n\r");
            NSLog(@"row count: %lid Content: %@",rowcount, [contentArray objectAtIndex:rowcount]);
            rowcount++;   // this section works

        }

        // parse into 2d array with rows and items in each row
        // this section is bogus - I am really clueless on how to proceed.
        itemcount=0;
        for (NSString *item in contentArray) {
           NSArray *itemArray = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            // log first item

           NSLog(@"\n\r");
            NSLog(@"item count: %lid Content: %@",itemcount, [itemArray objectAtIndex:rowcount]);
            itemcount++;
       }        
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In short you have a contentArray and you want to make 2D array ?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not sequential or has gaps in the numeric indexes you want to use you would be best off using a dictionary with NSNumber keys. Something along like this may do what you want.

```
NSMutableDictionary *outputData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity: 5];
NSUInteger sectionColumnIndex = 3; // What ever column you want to use as the top level
for (NSString *item in contentArray) {
    NSArray *itemArray = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSNumber *sectionNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[itemArray objectAtIndex: sectionColumnIndex] intValue]];
    if(![outputData objectForKey: sectionNumber]){
        NSMutableArray *sectionEntries = [NSMutableArray arrayWitCapacity: 5];
        [outputData setObject: sectionEntries forKey: sectionNumber];
    }

    NSMutableArray *sectionEntries = [outputData objectForKey: sectionNumber];
    [sectionEntries addObject: itemArray];
}
```

NOTE: This probably has typos in it but should get you started.